# curl, how to use file_get_contents?

Tags: php, curl

i have a php script like this:

```
    <?php
$likes = 'https://graph.facebook.com/google';
$fb = file_get_contents($likes);
$fb_array=json_decode($fb,true);
$all_likes = $fb_array['likes'];
$english_format = number_format($all_likes);
?>
```

what happens sometimes is that the url is failing and i get something like this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/google) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/html/google/index.php on line 774
```

I was wondering if there is a way for the code to degrade gracefully, because is bringing my entire website down.

I was thinking if there is a php or curl alternative to handle that error.

any ideas?

Thanks

edit:
i could so this:

```
    <?php
$likes = 'https://graph.facebook.com/google';
if(!@file_get_contents($likes)){
    $english_format = 123;
} else {
$fb = file_get_contents($likes);
$fb_array=json_decode($fb,true);
$all_likes = $fb_array['likes'];
$english_format = number_format($all_likes);
    } 
?>
```

but it still slows down my website

Comment: Why are you using error suppression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle HTTP errors with `file_get_contents` by using a [stream context](http://php.net/stream_context_create):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
         'ignore_errors' => true,
    ),
));

$fb = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$code = substr($http_response_header[0], strpos($http_response_header[0], ' ')+1);

if ($code != 200) {
    // there might be a problem
}
```

Additionally, `display_errors` should be `Off` on production environments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like @ because this one makes code execution slower. But you can use code below because if all is ok you make two file_get_contents and it's slow

```
$likes = 'https://graph.facebook.com/google';
$result = @file_get_contents($likes);
if(empty($result)){
    $english_format = 123;
} else {
    $fb_array=json_decode($result,true);
    $all_likes = $fb_array['likes'];
    $english_format = number_format($all_likes);
}
```

Comment: "I don't like @ because this one makes code execution slower." There is  a bigger problem with `@`

Comment: I know about this one but one of causes in the code is calling two file_get_contents

Answer (score -1):

You can setup an [Error Handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to catch (and politely manage) the error.

Alternatively you can @[suppress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) the error, then just check to make sure `$fb` is valid before continuing.

Comment: @NullUserException: Not endorsing so much as it is a viable option. Just because it's not the best option, doesn't mean it's not an option nonetheless. It's in PHP, it's capable of being [mis]used. I would either find the root of the problem or use a custom error handler, personally.

Comment: @Brad Christie, +1. I agree for the mindset. Bad option is still an option. :). Keep it simple stupid (KISS)